# How can I hide an event from another calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I can prevent an event from a calendar I control from displaying on my calendar, by deleting it.  I would like a way to similarly remove from my display an event from another calendar that I'm viewing, without hiding EVERYTHING from that calendar.  Is there a way to remove events from those other calendars?

Answer (score 1):

Not that this is the answer you're looking for, but I'm 99% sure the answer is simply: you can't.

I guess if this is something you absolutely had to have, you could write your own version of Google Calendar using [the API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/), but that seems like a long way to go for one feature. I'd recommend you [submit feedback to Google](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6110973), but don't know that it's something they'd consider adding.